# # Oracle Apex 5.1 - Creating Custom Template and use it in Database Application

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I need a help in creating following structure using apex 5.1. I have tried it to achieve in different ways

I have created a demo app on apex.oracle.com

1. I have three different tables Escalation, Issues and Comments
2. The Flow of the data is 1 Escalation - Many Issues and 1 Issue  - Many Comments.
3. I want to develop a custom template in which I can have nested Editable Grids with Collapsible Rows.
4. In the below mock up I should have a single page with 3 different editable collapsible grids.
5. It is similar to nested report but I need All the tables should work like an editable grids.

Comment: I am unable to add my mockup UI but I want an editable Drill Down Structure.